# Accessing Visio UML Data

Tags: xml, uml, visio

I'm using Visio 2013 Professional trial, I would like to be able to read the data to use it elsewhere. Preferably XML, but as long as I can read it I don't really care. Is there a way I can do this?

My goal is to create UML Diagrams in Visio, and then be able to extract the data for automatic code generation.

I've searched online and every source seems to tell me or imply that Visio has an in-built XML format, but I don't seem to have it. Is it something I'm missing due to trial version, was it removed from Visio 2013, or am I just skipping over something by mistake?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to export Visio UML diagrams into "XMI", an XML format.

Any of these links might point you in the right direction:

- Visio UML to XMI export functionality:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140339%28v=office.10%29.aspx

- Download XMI .dll from CNet:

http://download.cnet.com/UML-To-XMI-Export/3000-2206_4-10732176.html

- Create XMI for import into IBM Rational Software Architect:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/import-microsoft-visio-diagrams-2/

- XMI export with ESRI:

http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/26105

Comment: All of these resources are the same ones I've found so far. The microsoft link to the XMLExport is not found, the CNet download will get me stuck as I can't find the .src files due to it referencing Visio 2003, and the last link requires the first link to work. This is where I got stuck :/

Comment: It used to work fine, and I assumed XMIExport.dll would be freely downloadable from Microsoft.  I guess that's not the case with Visio 2013.  Q: Do you really need Visio?  For example, have you considered trying the Eclipse UML modeler?  http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-designer-eclipse-kepler-version#.U50hKihroqs

Comment: If I absolutely HAVE to I can work with something else, but I won't give up with Visio because it is ideal for me :P

Comment: @Matt [XML Metadata Interchange (*.xmi)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) is the key. It is the standardized UML file format, no matter what tool you use. If your tool does not support it then it is not UML modeling tool, it is only picture drawing tool or you have a vendor-lock