# Reading class attribute value from Visio document using C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, shapes, visio

I need to read all the class attributes from a class diagram in Visio and write the attributes and its properties value into the Excel.

Am using `office.interop.visio`  reference. I need to read a class like of below:

[image]

How to read the attribute from the class in C#?

similar like we can access the built in property of BMPN attributes by

```
string value = shape.get_CellsSRC(
                        (short)visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp,
                        iRow, (short)visio.VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue).get_ResultStr(visio.VisUnitCodes.visNoCast);
```

Comment: Which attribute properties?

Comment: @stakx need to read the whole attribute

Answer (score 1):

The Visio UML addon is a proprietary solution from Microsoft, and does not have a documented API to access it's data. Similar thing with the "Database" reverse-engineering addon (actually they share the same model).

What is supported, is XMI export. See here: [Accessing Visio UML Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225433/accessing-visio-uml-data)

There also exists an undocumented API (MODELENG) which could allow you to access the built-in data programmatically (check [this post](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=5853.msg23559#msg23559) for an example). Note that it does not exist anymore in Visio 2013 (as well as the UML/Database addons)

Comment: is it possible only through XMI ..?/

Comment: The documented way is only through XMI, as far as I know.

Comment: cay you please suggest me some website for reading class attributes through XMI in visio

Comment: Please check the link to the similar stackoverflow post in my answer.. it provides relevant links.

Comment: You cannot do that with UML similarly to BPMN, because UML model data, unlike BPMN for example, is not stored in shapes. It is stored separately in a binary BLOB with proprietary format. Thus XMI and undocumented libraries.

Comment: Note that this is different in Visio 2013 (the UML addon was removed, and now in UML templates in Visio 2013 all data is in shapes; however you get this at cost of losing most of sophisticated UML-related modeling functionality you had in Visio 2010 and before)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70126/discussion-between-arshad-and-nikolay).